# Framelayout doesn't show up in main activity

Tags: java, android, layout, android-framelayout

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

The fragment I send to fragment_content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!-- Listview -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvEvent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:divider="#D0D0D0"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:showDividers="middle"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the toolbar show up, I can do actions with it but there is nothing in my Framelayout? If I delete the include (toolbar) then I can see the content in my Framelayout. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have set the height of your toolbar to `wrap_content`, I assume you want a vertical layout, but your top level `LinearLayout` is set to horizontal.  Change the `orientation` to `vertical`.